# how can i pass props to parent and call a function at the same time within the same obj(tag)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass props to parent and at the same time call a function

```
handleClick(bgColor,presedentName) {
    //do Somthing
}


    <div >
        <span className="imgSpan">
            <img alt="pic" onClick={()=>this.handleClick("red","George H. W. Bush"),this.props.presedentSelected}  src="./Images/George H. W. Bush.jpg"/>
        </span>
        <h3 id="presedentName">{this.state.presedentSelected.name}</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: onClick you want to call two functions?

Comment: no i want to notify the parent and call a function in the child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preconfigure your function with multiple parameter sets.

```
handleClick = (bgColor, presedentName) => ev => {
    const { passPresedent, presedentSelected } = this.props
    passPresedent(presedentSelected, presedentName)
}

<div>
    <span className="imgSpan">
        <img alt="pic" onClick={this.handleClick("red","George H. W. Bush")}  src="./Images/George H. W. Bush.jpg"/>
    </span>
    <h3 id="presedentName">{this.state.presedentSelected.name}</h3>
</div>
```

Then, simply pass the function to your child component :

```
<Child passPresedent={this.myfunc}>
```

You can now use both the values you sent in your function from the parent component :

```
myfunc = (presedentSelected, presedentName) => {
    // Do stuff
}
```